# How to stop QtLinguist from starting when Visual Studio wants to show TypeScript file?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2017, qt-linguist

After installing Qt tools for Visual Studio, whenever I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click a class name, Qt Linguist starts:

[image]

This prevents me from looking up type definitons, even though I can see Visual Studio has parsed them. When I hover the type, it's clearly loaded:

[image]

That's a similar question to this one, but the answer suggest changing Windows settings for `.ts` files. But on my PC, Qt Linguist is not linked to `.ts` files:

[image]

I searched Visual Studio settings for "file", but I can't see any settings for file types.

Answer (score 0):

You might check`Tools -> Options` menu, and from there `Text Editor -> File Extensions`, if extension added something, or to override editor `ts` file extension.

[image]